# Easiest Way to install Zabbix in amazon linux 2 ami

Tags: zabbix, amazon-linux-2

is there any easy way to install **`zabbix`** on **`amazon linux 2 ami`**? I was following the official documentation but many issues came up.

First, php issue, i was following the installation process similar to cent os but it showed some error showing that rh-php72-mysqlnd and some other packages were not found.

Second, i couldn't create the database for zabbix, it give **`ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'zabbix'@'localhost'`** So i was just curious that is there any easy way to install zabbix on **amazon linux 2 ami** or is there any good alternative for zabbix in amazon linux 2 ami?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Found out that this question is not really valid because zabbix don't have support for **Amazon Linux 2 AMI**